# Injection specific to each module

Tags: angular

Someting I can't figure out in Angular.

I have 2 modules each using *MyService*, but I want this service to be configured in different way (so a non-singleton service) for each of thoses modules.

Let's say :

```
export class MyService {}

@NgModule({
  provider: [{ provide: MyService, useValue 'A' }]
}
export class ModuleA {
  constructor(test MyService) {
    console.log('ModuleA :', test); // expecting A
  }
}

@NgModule({
  provider: [{ provide: MyService, useValue 'B' }]
}
export class ModuleB {
  constructor(test MyService) {
    console.log('ModuleB :', test); // expecting B
  }
}
```

But *MyService* have the same value for both modules (singleton), either A or B depending on the one that init first.

I will have for instance :

> ModuleA: A
>
> ModuleB: A

I want each module to get a different injection, as specified in the modules configurations.

Comment: Try lazy loading the module.

Comment: Do you use @Injectable? I don't see it in the example provided.

Comment: @alt255, I tried, but didn't achieve a different result. Also with factories

Comment: @Giovani no need (pretty sure) as I'm "providing" the injection

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading modules will create separate instances of the provided service. [more info](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-it-bad-if-a-shared-module-provides-a-service-to-a-lazy-loaded-module)

You could also try using `@Inject()`.

```
export class MyService {}

@NgModule({
  provider: [{ provide: 'MyServiceA', useClass: MyService }]
}
export class ModuleA {
  constructor(@Inject('MyServiceA') test: MyService) {
      //new instance of MyService
  }
}

@NgModule({
  provider: [{ provide: 'MyServiceB', useClass: MyService }]
}
export class ModuleB {
  constructor(@Inject('MyServiceB') test: MyService) {
      //new instance of MyService
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. This break what I want to achieve, because you configure each injection of "MyService". In each services of a module, I don't want to choose which "MyService" to inject, only the one defined at the module level.